# Copy database between two amazon RDS instance on same region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have two rds instance as below

**RDS_instance_one**
Databases_name:
**db_one 

db_two**

**RDS_instance_two**
Databases_name:
**db_one

db _three**

Both rds are in same region, i want to copy **db_one** from **RDS_instance_one** to **RDS_instance_two** with different name, lets say **db_four** as same name is db is already in this rds instance. 
Mysql dump of this db fails as is huge in size and when dumping in some ec2 instance disk space full issue occurs.

So need way to directly make replica of db from one rds instance to another rds instance like we do replica of rds instance
If anyone could give some pointers will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: What database engine are you using? Is it MySQL?

Comment: did you try to increase the size of rds instance in proportion to your DB size and then tried again with the dump facility? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
yes its MySql
Engine version : 5.7.33

Comment: @JatinMehrotra
RDS RAM : 64 GB
Storage : 2444 GiB
Maximum storage threshold : 5000 GiB
i cannot increase more.